# Unable to launch the Ethereum studio IDE

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

I would like to use Ethereum IDE for development . I have created a account on ether.camp  but when I click on the icon Start Now , I always see the same screen - attached below

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I cannot see the Ethereum IDE?

Comment: But I can see the image clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Ethereum Studio IDE has been discontinued.

I suggest you check out [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) which is not as pretty but very versatile and you can also connect to your own node. It also has a debugger that starts being usable.